# Setting attribute during initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

The Model is:

```
class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :make_downcase_name
  after_initialize :make_downcase_name
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :downcase_name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  private

    def make_downcase_name
      if name != nil
        self.downcase_name ||= name.downcase
      end
    end
end
```

This test fails:

```
before do
  @persona = Persona.new(name: "Bazman")
end

subject { @persona }

describe "name with mixed case" do
  let(:mixed_case_name) { "TeRRy" }
  it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
    @persona.name = mixed_case_name
    @persona.save
    expect(@persona.reload.downcase_name).to eq mixed_case_name.downcase
  end
end
```

with the error message:

expected: "terry"

got: "bazman"

So that means in the test when @persona.save is called, the before_save callback is not changing TeRRy's downcase_name to terry, so the line

```
self.downcase_name ||= name.downcase
```

is failing, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`downcase_name` is not updated to the lowercase version of the new name because of the way  `make_downcase_name` works.

```
self.downcase_name ||= name.downcase
```

This line can be explained as: if `downcase_name` is falsey (`nil` or `false`), then set it to `name.downcase`. Otherwise, leave it alone.

There are two options here. Either your spec is right and `downcase_name` should be updated when a new name is assigned, or your model is right and `downcase_name` should never change once it has first been assigned.

### Option 1: The spec is right

In this case, you need to fix your model:

```
def make_downcase_name
  return unless name

  self.downcase_name = name.downcase
end
```

That's it!

### Option 2: The model is right

If this is true, you need to make sure you're creating a new `Persona` in your spec. First, let's do a small refactoring of your spec to declare variables using `let` rather than using an instance variable:

```
let(:persona) { Persona.new(name: 'Bazman' }
subject       { persona }

describe "name with mixed case" do
  let(:mixed_case_name) { "TeRRy" }

  it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
    persona.name = mixed_case_name
    persona.save
    expect(persona.reload.downcase_name).to eq mixed_case_name.downcase
  end
end
```

For the `name with mixed case` scenario, you can now easily create a new `Persona` instance:

```
let(:persona) { Persona.new(name: 'Bazman') }
subject       { persona }

describe "name with mixed case" do
  let(:mixed_case_name) { "TeRRy" }
  let(:persona)         { Persona.new }

  it "should be saved as all lower-case" do
    persona.name = mixed_case_name
    persona.save
    expect(persona.downcase_name).to eq mixed_case_name.downcase
  end
end
```

Comment: I should have said, downcase_name should be updated every time name is changed (via edit). So the spec is correct. It now works perfectly. I see now using ||= was stupid - this wouldn't allow downcase_name to be updated. Thank you very much!

Comment: `return unless name` ensures that the code below isn't run in case name is `nil`. I replaced your original `if name != nil ... end` since the early return is easier to read than the if clause.

Comment: Got it. Your code is much more elegant! Thanks again.